# Point out my fallacy, in sequence and series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

> The sum of the first $n$--terms of the series $1^2+2\cdot2^2+3^2+2\cdot4^2+\cdots$ is $\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}{2}$, when $n$ is even. When $n$ is odd, the sum is?

I got the correct answer when is replaced $n\rightarrow (n+1)$ to make above valid for odd, but when I tried the different approach then something following had happened.

For $n$ **even**, last term $=n$ which is even and term before it $=n-1$ which is odd. Clubbing all odds and evens separately as follows:

$\big(1^2+3^2+\cdots +(n-1)^2\big)+2\big(2^2+4^2+\cdots+n^2\big)=\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}{2}\tag{1}$

For $n$ **odd**, last term $=n$ which is odd and term before it $=n-1$ which is even. Clubbing all odds and evens separately as follows:

$\big(1^2+3^2+\cdots +n^2\big)+2\big(2^2+4^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2\big)\tag*{}$

$=\big(1^2+3^2+\cdots +(n-1)^2\big)+2\big(2^2+4^2+\cdots+n^2\big)-n^2+(n-1)\tag*{}$

From equation $(1)$

$=\dfrac{n(n+1)^2}{2}-n^2+(n-1)\tag*{}$

And answer given is: $\dfrac{n^2(n+1)}{2}$

please help.

Comment: Have you checked by hand for some small values of $n$ which answer is correct?

Comment: @Mastrem no is answer wrong?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you have one answer, but it should be another. Maybe the answer given is incorrect and you were right after all. The easiest way to check this, is to plug in some small values of $n$ and see which of the two is correct

Comment: For $n$ odd case, you have added an extra unnecessary term $(n-1)$.

Comment: @stud_iisc for $n$ odd $n-1$ is even.

Answer (score 2):

> $$1^2+2^2+3^2+...N^2=\frac {N (N+1)(2N+1)}{6} $$

If $n $ is odd if the form $2p+1$,
the sum is

$$1+2.2^2+3^2+...2. (2p)^2+(2p+1)^2=$$

$$(1+2^2+3^2+... (2p+1)^2)+(2^2+4^2+... (2p)^2=$$

$$\frac {n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+4.\frac {p (p+1)(2p+1)}{6} =$$

$$\frac {n (n+1)(2n+1)+(n-1)(n+1)n}{6}=$$
$$\frac {n ^2(n+1)}{2} $$

Comment: ok thanks, but where I went wrong?

Comment: @mnulb Just after : From equation 1. you applied the formula for n which is odd instead (n-1).

Comment: I wrote sum for $n$ odd, then tried split it into even type sum (or in equation 1 type) to use {n*(n+1)^2}/2, and I didn't apply formula for odd, just assume n is odd so summation will end in "n" which is odd, and before this term we have our even = n-1. I wrote all odds in first brackets and even in second taking out 2 common.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be even. Then:

$$S(n+1)-S(n)=(n+1)^2 \Rightarrow$$
$$S(n+1)=\frac{n(n+1)^2}{2}+(n+1)^2=\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is ambiguous notation.

You say that $n$ is odd, and you write $1^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2,$ which makes sense: it is a finite sequence of squares of consecutive odd numbers from $1$ to $n.$
But in the very same equation you write 
$2^2+4^2+\cdots+n^2.$

What does the second expression even *mean?* It cannot be a sequence of even numbers, because $n$ is odd. It is not a sequence of odd numbers either. Does it start even and change to odd somewhere?
Where does it change? When it changes from even to odd, does it include the squares of two consecutive numbers or does it skip a number?

Then, having written a sum of two expressions for $n$ odd that makes no sense but that *looks* (notationally) like an expression whose value you know when $n$ is even, you assume the same formula will apply also when $n$ is odd, and you apply it.

By the time you have done these two things, there is no reason to think that the result will have any relationship to any true mathematical fact.

Answer (score 0):

For $n$ odd case: $$\big(1^2+3^2+\cdots +n^2\big)+2\big(2^2+4^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2\big) \\= \big(1^2+3^2+\cdots +n^2\big)+2\big(2^2+4^2+\cdots+(n+1)^2\big) - 2(n+1)^2 \\= \frac{(n+1)(n+2)^2}{2} - 2(n+1)^2 \\= \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}.$$

Let $T1$ denote number of terms contributed by odd indexes (for example $1^2, 3^2$ etc) and $T2$ denote number of terms contributed by even indexes (for example $2.2^2, 2.4^2$ etc). Note that, for $n$ odd case, $T1 = T2 + 1$ and for $n$ even case, $T1 = T2$.